# Built-In Trackpad and Keyboard Unresponsive after Sleep or Restart

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, performance, trackpad

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2008) that's currently running 10.7.3. I've been finding that it will intermittently freeze and then I have to shut down and restart the computer, but sometimes that will not fix the problem.

If I plug in an external mouse and keyboard, then I can move the cursor and type again, but as soon as I remove them, the problem persists.

I've tried resetting the P-RAM, reinstalling Lion, installing a new HD, and I've had the graphics chip tested and it's performing properly. If you have any suggestions on how to fix or diagnose, that would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Upgrading to 10.7.4 might help.

Comment: Same bug happening sometime with Mountain Lion

Comment: I have the same issue with 2018 MBP and Catalina. Annoying!

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff I have the same issue. Might be related to running VmWare fusion vms

Comment: @jontro It does correlate, since I haven’t been running VMs for about a month and that issue stopped happening as well. Thank you for the observation, I didn’t make the connection

Comment: Same issue with a 2019 16-inch MBP. I've only observed this to happen when I have my Yubikey attached while powering on the system, though that could be coincidence. Any chance you have any kind of external device that emulates a keyboard attached?

Comment: (...that said, I _do_ use VMware Fusion, so that fits for me as well).

Comment: Same issue for me, 2015 MBP with MacOS13.2 but was also happening with 12.6. I found if I connect a USB keyboard and mouse, those will work even when the built in keyboard and trackpad do not.

Answer (score 1):

So, correct me if I'm wrong, your problem occurs when you open your MacBook Pro?

Resetting your PRAM won't work. Try [resetting your SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964). This is responsible for the responses when opening and closing your lid.

Comment: The problem can occur even if the lid is left open, which would be the case during a restart. And sometimes it becomes unresponsive while using the computer. Nonetheless, I haven't tried resetting the SMC and will give it a try. Good suggestion, Michiel, thank you.

For the record I've also tried turning off Spotlight indexing and that didn't fix anything either.

Comment: Ok, great. Let me know how it went!

Comment: Resetting the SMC didn't fix the problem either

Comment: Just to review, here's everything I've tried:
- Reset PRAM
- Reset SMC
- Disable Spotlight indexing
- Re-install OS
- Use a different Hard Drive
- Tested the graphics chip for defects
- Ran a permissions repair

Comment: Was it a clean reinstall? Have you tried booting it in safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

**Resetting the SMC** should fix the issue. Note that this will reboot the MacBook, so you will lose any unsaved work.

- Shut down the computer.
- Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to
  the Mac if its not already connected.
- On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option
  keys and the power button at the same time.
- Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
- Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Note: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC

Comment: This answer is copyed and pasted from another [AD question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/how-do-i-fix-non-responsive-keyboard-and-trackpad-after-sleep-on-macbook-pro-ret) and did not solve the issue in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem.

Installing OS X 10.9 Mavericks resolved it for me.

Comment: I still experiencing this issue on 10.9.2.

Comment: 10.10 also with 2015 13 mbp retina