# How do I fix non-responsive keyboard and trackpad after sleep on MacBook Pro Retina 15?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake, trackpad

I'm having a problem with my MacBook Pro Retina 15.

I close the screen to put it to sleep.  When I open it back up, the screen wakes up, but the keyboard and trackpad do not work.

If I plug in a USB keyboard, it works fine and I see a message on the screen that says:

**Bluetooth Mouse or Trackpad Setup**

**There isn't a wireless mouse or trackpad connected.**

I'm running 10.8.5.

Comment: My trackpad on macbook pro retina 15" with osx 10.8.5 stop working after enter sleep mode

Comment: I thought the latest update fixed this, but then it happened again.

Comment: Mavericks resolved this for me.

Comment: I still have this on a Macbook Pro 16'' (2019) with 10.15.5 on it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have stopped since I upgraded to OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I'll link this to another question we have on this topic but keep it around so that people searching for the issue get both sets of answers when they arrive to the site.

Comment: I am on 10.9.2 and still experiencing this issue

Comment: 10.15.5 and still an issue for me. (MacBook Pro 16'')

Answer (score 0):

**Resetting the SMC** should do the trick. This seems to have fixed the issue. Note that this will reboot the MacBook, so you will lose any unsaved work.

- Shut down the computer.
- Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to
  the Mac if its not already connected.
- On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option
  keys and the power button at the same time.
- Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
- Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Note: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.

Comment: Resetting the SMC normally is for problems with power, fans, GPU target mode display and CPU clock rate control. Is there something about this other than the reboot that would actually help for trackpad / bluetooth pairing issues?

Comment: Resetting the SMC didn't help me with this issue.

Comment: Did not help :(

Comment: Resetting the SMC does help sometimes.